# node.js: JSON dot notation + access array key

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, syntax

I have a site setup using node.js, express, mongoDB & mongoose. Mongoose is giving me an array that contains this:

```
[ { title: 'HTML in depth',
    author: 'kevin vanhove',
    _id: 53039f264a6324978c70084b,
    chapters: 
     [ { _id: 53039f264a6324978c70084d,
         content: '/jow',
         title: 'History of HTML' },
       { _id: 53039f264a6324978c70084c,
         content: '/w3c',
         title: 'What is the W3C' } ],
    __v: 0 } ]
```

I'm getting this result in my terminal using this code:

```
function indexData(books){

console.log(books)

res.render("index.html", {context:books, partials:{footer:"footer", header:"header"}})
```

}

Now i'm trying to access the value in chapters[0].title, but i'm getting an error:

```
console.log(books[0].chapters[0].title)

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

I'm confused here, am i accessing the value using the right dot notation?

**UPDATE 1: complete terminal output**

```
24 Feb 10:56:47 - [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
24 Feb 10:56:47 - [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Mongoose: books.find({}) { fields: undefined }  

/Users/kevinvanhove/Documents/work/projects/basing/business/klanten/javascript/nodeJS/express/basing/routes/routes.js:45
        console.log(books[0].chapters[0].title)
                                     ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at indexData (/Users/kevinvanhove/Documents/work/projects/basing/business/klanten/javascript/nodeJS/express/basing/routes/routes.js:45:32)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (/Users/kevinvanhove/Documents/work/projects/basing/business/klanten/javascript/nodeJS/express/basing/routes/routes.js:37:31)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (/Users/kevinvanhove/Documents/work/projects/basing/business/klanten/javascript/nodeJS/express/basing/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:177:8)
    at Promise.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Promise.emit (/Users/kevinvanhove/Documents/work/projects/basing/business/klanten/javascript/nodeJS/express/basing/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:84:38)
    at Promise.fulfill (/Users/kevinvanhove/Documents/work/projects/basing/business/klanten/javascript/nodeJS/express/basing/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:97:20)
    at /Users/kevinvanhove/Documents/work/projects/basing/business/klanten/javascript/nodeJS/express/basing/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1052:26
    at model.Document.init (/Users/kevinvanhove/Documents/work/projects/basing/business/klanten/javascript/nodeJS/express/basing/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:250:11)
    at completeMany (/Users/kevinvanhove/Documents/work/projects/basing/business/klanten/javascript/nodeJS/express/basing/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1050:12)
    at Object.cb (/Users/kevinvanhove/Documents/work/projects/basing/business/klanten/javascript/nodeJS/express/basing/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1017:11)
24 Feb 10:56:49 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

**Partial solution:**

I was trying to get to the chapters data. Updating my mongoose schema to include the chapters data did the trick.

```
var booksSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 title: String,
 author: String,
 chapters: [
    {
        title: String,
        content: String
    }
 ]

});
```

Comment: Are you sure you're showing us the right console output? Copy-pasting the JSON document and accessing `books[0].chapters[0].title` [seems to work](https://gist.github.com/PaulMougel/9184937).

Comment: Hi, yes... i update my post, this contains the complete output.

Comment: Looks like that *sometimes* MongoDB doesn't find the documents you're looking for and thus returns an empty object. You should check the `err` parameter of the callback.

Comment: thx, i'm getting 'null' if i check the value of err

Comment: As a side note, if i try this, then i do get the value: console.dir(books[0].title)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work an that way on the Mongoose (server) side. The result from `find()` is a **cursor** that you need to either iterate or convert via toArray from the native driver part. Something like this

(Assuming Schema `Books`):

```
Books.collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, results) {

  // results is an array that you can do something with here.

});
```

Of course if you have defined additional Schema for arrays and their documents that **are not** [**embedded**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.8.x/docs/embedded-documents.html), then this is going to hurt a bit more and you need to use the iterative methods to get your results as an array.

If you want **specific** items from your `books` and sub-items within, then you would be better of tuning your find query using the [operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/) rather than returning all results. Or even the [aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) may be of some help.

Comment: Thx for you answer, i'm still need to check it out, but if i need to do a conversion, then way does this work? console.log(books[0].title //gives me HTML in depth

Comment: @kevinius you are talking about inspecting this in your browser client here right? If you return all your results to your client then you can inspect that way. But you treat it **differently** server side. That's what you are being told in the answer.

Comment: I understand that i have to treat it differently on the server side. But outputting to console.log is 'server side'? So i can access books[0].title on server & client side but i can't access the values deeper into the array (like books[0].chapters[0].title. I'm very confused at the moment... sorry...

Comment: Could it be that is the case because the subdocuments (chapters) don't have a mongoose schema? I only have this schema set up: var booksSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 title: String,
 author: String
});

Comment: @kevinius The fact is **it's not actually an array** and certainly not in the *native* form that I mentioned but likely there is a Mongoose helper that makes things *appear* as an array at that level. You can work with what I have proposed, or perhaps move this to chat? Your question as it stands, has been answered in the sense of explaining why what you were trying to do won't work, and what to do so you can do it in the same way. Also a pointer to what you probably **should** be doing. If you are still having problems grasping this, then perhaps another question is required.

Comment: I'll create a new question, thx..., i have accepted your answer.